# How to get the latest records of the multiple values of same column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a database with following structure

```
 url  update_time                 dns_time
 -------------------------------
 url1  2013-04-05 08:03:23       0.897
 url2  2013-09-03 08:03:45       0.765
 url1  2013-08-23 09:23:34       2.457
 url3  2013-08-34 09:45:47       1.456
 //and so on
```

Now I want to retrieve only latest records of each url. How to achieve this using PostgreSQL select query.

I tried using

```
 select url,
        update_time,
        dns_time 
 from dns_lookup_table 
 where url in('url1','url2','url3') 
 order by desc limit 1
```

But it is giving me the *url3* latest value that is last record. I tried with **desc limit 3** for getting latest values of all 3 urls. I want to retrieve the latest records of *url1*, *url2*, *url3*. Only latest records. And the table `dns_lookup_table` has records that comes into it dynamically. Sometimes the url record can not be inserted if not available. So order is missing. So I think it is not possible with `desc limit`.

Comment: what is the type of update_time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*So order is missing*"?

Comment: Order of Urls will be missing if I use desc limit 5..If record is not available having the url which is not inserted into database

Comment: update_time is of type timestamp in postgresql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
 FROM dns_lookup_table lut
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM dns_lookup_table nx
   WHERE nx.url = lut.url
     AND nx.update_time > lut.update_time
   );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a window function to get the latest row for each URL:

```
select *
from (
   select url, 
          update_time, 
          dns_time, 
          row_number() over (partition by url order by update_time desc) as rnk
   from dns_lookup_table
) as t
where rnk = 1
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fbd38/1

---

*Edit*

You can also use something like this:

```
select *
from dns_lookup_table lt
  join (
     select url, 
            max(update_time) as latest_time
     from dns_lookup_table
     group by url
  ) as mt on mt.latest_time = lt.update_time 
         and mt.url = lt.url;
```

Comment: I am using postgresql 9.0 version

Comment: @user2515189: then the window function will work. You probably copied incorrect code. Can you upload a sample to http://sqlfiddle.com showing the problem.