# PostgreSQL query using subquery is giving exception

Tags: postgresql, select, max

This is my postgres query (using postgres 9.0 version) for selecting the latest records of each url. My dns_lookup_table consists of different values for each url at different times.

url1,url2,url3 are 'text' type, update_time is 'timestamp with timezone' and dns_time is 'numeric' type.

```
select url,
       dns_time,
       update_Time 
from dns_lookup_table 
where url in('url1', 'url2','url3') 
 and  update_time = max(select to_char(update_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

Please help me I am getting syntax error at "select"

Comment: Always show your PostgreSQL version (`select version()`) and the **exact text of the error message**.

Comment: BTW, I didn't downvote this, but given how little the question you posted has to do with the real problem you're having I'm not too surprised it *was* down-voted. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info and of course http://stackoverflow.com/help for advice on asking questions that can clearly and quickly answered.

Comment: The question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17361081/2235885 was already answered (by me)

Answer (score 1):

You're using an incorrect subquery syntax:

```
select url,dns_time,update_Time
from dns_lookup_table
where url in('url1', 'url2','url3')
  and update_time=max(select to_char(update_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You forgot to wrap the subquery in parentheses:

```
  and update_time=max((select to_char(update_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')));
                      ^                                                ^
                      |-------------- extra parens --------------------|
```

but in this case you don't need a subquery at all, you can just invoke the functions with simple nesting:

```
  and update_time=max(to_char(update_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

It's still nonsense, though. You're comparing `update_time` to the text conversion of `update_time` to `text`. Which doesn't make sense. Why are you even trying to compare `update_time` to its self anyway? Maybe you meant to do a subquery `FROM` another table? If so, you're usually better off doing a simple join instead.

Your further comments suggest that you really want `date_trunc`. If I widly guess what you're trying to do as:

*Select all rows where the `update_time` is the same, ignoring seconds, as the most recent `update_time` in the table*

... then you might write:

```
SELECT url,dns_time,update_Time
FROM dns_lookup_table 
WHERE url IN ('url1','url2','url3')
  and date_trunc('minute',update_time) = (
    SELECT date_trunc('minute', max(update_time))
    FROM dns_lookup_table 
    WHERE url IN ('url1','url2','url3')
  );
```

though this won't use any index you might've defined on `update_time` for the filter. You'd need to create an index on `date_trunc('minute', update_time)` or rephrase the query to use `BETWEEN` and a range created from an `INTERVAL`.

Comment: Giving me exception:operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone = text: select url,dns_time,update_Time from dns_lookup_table where url in('url1', 'url2','url3') and update_time=max((select to_char(update_time,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')))

Comment: @user2515189 Answer updated. Your query is completely nonsensical.

Comment: I want the latest records.But I am using same update_time for each url.But the java program may have seconds differ while running all the urls,But minutes and hours with date may be the same.So I am extracting time upto minutes for getting latest records of each url.

Comment: @user2515189 Consider posting a new question that explains the problem you're trying to solve, with the schema definitions, sample data, and expected results. See the "asking better questions" section of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info . It sounds like you might want `date_trunc`, but it's hard to tell.